# My angular controller doesnt send data to c# controller

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

Hello everyone,
                I couldn't send data from my angular controller to my c# controller.Whenever the controller is called it throws out error callback.I have tried different ways,but i couldn't rectify it.Am i making any mistake in defining correct url.I am really clueless.

**Angular controller**

```
 var httpTimeout = 1800000;
                var httpTimeoutSearch = 3600000;
                angular.module('MyApp', [])
                var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
                app.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
                    alert("in");
                    $scope.Username = "";
                    $scope.Password = "";

                    $scope.Login = function () {
                        if ($scope.Username != null && $scope.username != "") {
                            if ($scope.Password != null && $scope.password != "") {
                                try {
                                    var obj = { UserName: $scope.Username, Password: $scope.Password };
                                    alert(obj.Username);
                                    $http({
                                        method: 'POST',
                                        data: obj,
                                        url: '/Account/Maxi',
                                        timeout: httpTimeout,
                                    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                                        alert("sucess");
                                    }, function errorCallback(response) {
                                        alert("error");
                                    });
                                }
                                catch (ex)
                                { alert(ex); }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }]);
```

**C# controller**

```
 [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Maxi(LoginModel data)
        {
            string strReturn = "";
            string ConStr = "";
            string Code = "";
            if (data.UserName != null)
           {
               if (data.Password != null)
               {


                   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                   SqlParameter[] parameters =
                    {  

                     new SqlParameter( "@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20) { Value = data.UserName } ,
                     new SqlParameter("@Roll_No", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = data.Password  } ,



                    };
                   ConStr = "Data Source=" + "192.168.1.9" + ";Initial Catalog=" + "MyFistDataBase" + ";User id=" + "sa" + ";Password=" + "123" + ";";
                   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
                   {
                       using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Maxi", con))
                       {
                           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                           SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                           cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
                           da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                           da.Fill(ds);
                       }
                   }

                   string errmsg = "";

                   if (errmsg != "")
                   {
                       Code = "0"; strReturn = errmsg;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                       {
                           if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                           {
                               Code = "1";

                               foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                               {
                                   strReturn += dr[0].ToString();
                               }
                               if (strReturn == "1")
                               {
                                   Console.Write("Updated");
                               }

                           }
                           //TripDT = TripDT.ToShortDateString();
                       }

                   } 
               } 
           }
            return View(data);
        }
```

**Object Model**

```
 public class LoginModel
    {
         [Key]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misspelling the sending KVP data.

```
var obj = { Username: $scope.Username, Passord: $scope.Password };
```

should be

```
var obj = { UserName: $scope.Username, Password: $scope.Password };
```

for verificationToken error need to add this data to json also

```
 "__RequestVerificationToken" : your_html_value
```

see how to add this key data [HERE in Detail](https://benohead.com/blog/2014/01/14/asp-net-mvc-the-required-anti-forgery-form-field-__requestverificationtoken-is-not-present/)

Comment: I have changed it ,still the same problem persists.

Comment: it should be `UserName` also... edit that as well. moreover, what you see in the response in errorCallback?

Comment: It just shows "error" which i have represented in error callback portion. function errorCallback(response) {
                                        alert("error");
                                    });

Comment: use `consol.log(response)` instead of `alert(error)` so you can view detail error

Comment: This is my error:The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present."